# Tree of logic puzzle

Tags: forest, logicpuzzle

I want to build a tree of the 8-puzzle. By using `logicpuzzle` and `forest` I got to this point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\usepackage{forest}

\newenvironment{eight}[1][]{%
\begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=3,columns=3,#1]
\begin{puzzleforeground}
\framepuzzle
\end{puzzleforeground}
}{\end{logicpuzzle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[\begin{eight}
\setrow{3}{1,4,2}
\setrow{2}{6,,5}
\setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight}
[\begin{eight}
\setrow{3}{1,4,2}
\setrow{2}{,6,5}
\setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight} 
\begin{eight}
\setrow{3}{1,,2}
\setrow{2}{6,4,5}
\setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight} 
\begin{eight}
\setrow{3}{1,4,2}
\setrow{2}{6,5,}
\setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight} 
\begin{eight}
\setrow{3}{1,4,2}
\setrow{2}{6,3,5}
\setrow{1}{7,,8}
\end{eight}]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

But the result I get has these problems:

- The numbers don't appear inside the grid
- The lines connecting the starting configuration to the next four are not displayed correctly
- The whole drawing is shifted to the right and gets out of the page

[image: Result of logic puzzle tree]

Comment: 1) Missing numbers are caused by nested `tikzpicture` environments, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279210). 2) Missing lines connecting forest nodes are caused by wrong usage: it should be `[A [B][C][D][E]]`, not `[A [B C D E]]`. 3) Shifted drawing could be the combination of page margin, too long drawing, and forest node separation and anchors. If all you want is several connected 3x3 matrixes, then manually draw them in tikz (to get rid of the nesting issue) could be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code helps to solve the issues.

[image: b]

The `geometry` package helps to set better margins for the tree and fit it on the page. Also added  `scale=0.9, width= 3cm,` to control the size of the puzzles and their separation.

The next row will have 12 puzzles. Try `\documentclass[landscape]{article}`.

`\begin{forest}for tree={l sep=4em}` adds extra  vertical space from the parent node.

Saving the environment `eight` in boxes and the using them to build the tree solves the problem of the disappearing numbers (and simplifies the code of the tree).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\usepackage{forest}

\newenvironment{eight}[1][]{%
    \begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=3,columns=3, scale=0.9, width= 3cm, #1]
        \begin{puzzleforeground}
            \framepuzzle    
    }{\end{puzzleforeground}\end{logicpuzzle}}

\newsavebox{\tempi}
\newsavebox{\tempii}
\newsavebox{\tempiii}
\newsavebox{\tempvi}
\newsavebox{\tempv}
\sbox{\tempi}{%
\begin{eight}
    \setrow{3}{1,4,2}
    \setrow{2}{6,,5}
    \setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight}
}

\sbox{\tempii}{%
\begin{eight}
    \setrow{3}{1,4,2}
    \setrow{2}{,6,5}
    \setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight}
}

\sbox{\tempiii}{%
\begin{eight}
    \setrow{3}{1,,2}
    \setrow{2}{6,4,5}
    \setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight}
}
\sbox{\tempvi}{%
\begin{eight}
    \setrow{3}{1,4,2}
    \setrow{2}{6,5,}
    \setrow{1}{7,3,8}
\end{eight}
}
\sbox{\tempv}{%
\begin{eight}
    \setrow{3}{1,4,2}
    \setrow{2}{6,3,5}
    \setrow{1}{7,,8}
\end{eight}
}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}for tree={l sep=4em}
        [\usebox{\tempi}
        [\usebox{\tempii}][\usebox{\tempiii}][\usebox{\tempvi}][\usebox{\tempv}]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've ended up using [this solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380721/how-to-create-board-game-search-tree) but yours is interesting as well.